# Return Receipt Lotus Notes

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I have working code to send email on Lotus Notes.

I need to know if the e-mail was received.

I tried `.Document.ReturnReceipt = "1"`.

```vb
Sub Enviaremailnotes()
Dim Notes As Object
Dim db As Object
Dim WorkSpace As Object
Dim UIdoc As Object
Dim UserName As String
Dim MailDbName As String
Dim MailDoc As Object
Dim AttachME As Object
Dim EmbedObj As Object
Dim i As Long
   
Set Notes = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
Set db = Notes.GetDataBase(vbNullString, MailDbName)
Set WorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Call WorkSpace.ComposeDocument(, , "Memo")
Set UIdoc = WorkSpace.CurrentDocument


'If cells are null, such as email address, cc, etc, then ignore and dont paste into email
 On Error Resume Next
'Copy the email address from cell C19 into the TO: field in Lotus Notes
'Note: Addresses in this cell should be separated by a semicolon.
'Please change your current sheet's name from Sheet1 to your sheet's name


Recipient = Sheets("Plan1").Range("A2").Value
Call UIdoc.FieldSetText("EnterSendTo", Recipient)

'Copy the email address from cellC C20 into the CC: field in Lotus Notes
'Note: Addresses in this cell should be separated by a semicolon
ccRecipient = Sheets("Plan1").Range("B2").Value
Call UIdoc.FieldSetText("EnterCopyTo", ccRecipient)


'Copy the subject from cell C22 into the SUBJECT: field in Lotus Notes
Subject1 = "Carta AST/DELOG/AFRMM" & " " & Cells(2, 3) & "/2021 - " & " " & Cells(2, 4)
Call UIdoc.FieldSetText("Subject", Subject1)

'Copy the cells in the range (one column going down) into the BODY in Lotus Notes.
'You must set the last cell C47 to one cell below the range you wish to copy.

Call UIdoc.GotoField("Body")
body1 = Sheets("Plan1").Range("E16").Value
body1 = body1 & vbCrLf & Sheets("Plan1").Range("E17").Value ' Space
body1 = body1 & vbCrLf & Sheets("Plan1").Range("E18").Value
body1 = body1 & vbCrLf & Sheets("Plan1").Range("E19").Value
body1 = body1 & vbCrLf & Sheets("Plan1").Range("E20").Value ' Space

Call UIdoc.InsertText(body1)

Call UIdoc.InsertText(vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
Application.CutCopyMode = False    

With UIdoc
    .Document.ReturnReceipt = "1"
    .Document.SaveOptions = "1"
    .Document.MailOptions = "1"
    .Close
End With
       
Set UIdoc = Nothing: Set WorkSpace = Nothing
Set db = Nothing: Set Notes = Nothing
Set AttachME = Nothing
Set Session = Nothing
Set EmbedObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the recipients within your own Notes/Domino network? Return receipt usually does not work for internet recipients.

Comment: In fact in the SMTP specs, there's no guarantee of delivery and no mechanism for return receipts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the UI classes to generate the email, try rewriting the code to use the backend classes.
Back in 2011 I posted [a Lotusscript class](http://blog.texasswede.com/lotusscript-mail-notification-class/) on my blog, where you can see how to do that. It should not be hard to convert that to VBA and use in Excel.
It would be trivial to add a line to set the ReturnReceipt flag:

```
Call maildoc.ReplaceItemValue("ReturnReceipt", "1")
```